# How to stop propagation outside item rows

Tags: reactjs, dom-events, event-propagation

Research on propagation has not given me answers. I have a React list using divs. Each item has a clickable row that takes the user to another page. But within the row, there are dropdown elements for updating the item. `stopPropagation` has been added to the dropdowns so that the user does not go to another page.

However, if you open the dropdown and then click off to the side because you changed your mind, the row action gets triggered anyway and takes the user to another page. How do I stop that from happening? I cannot target only the row container for redirecting to another page because I can't seem to add a reference to that element that I can match on in `event.target`. Is there another way to achieve this?

DROPDOWN

```
const select = () => (
<Select value={value} onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}>
  {items.map((option) => (
      <MenuItem className={menuItemClass} key={option.id} value={option.id}>
        {option.name}
      </MenuItem>
    ))}
</Select>
)
```

ONCHANGE

```
const onChange = async (event) => {
   event.stopPropagation();
   updateItem();
   ...
```

ROW

```
<TableRowBody onClick={(event) => onClickRow(rowItem, event)}>
   ...
   <select />
   ...
</TableRowBody>
```

ONCLICKROW

```
const onClickRow = (value, event) => {
    setValue(value);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the clickable element can be a sibling of the select, you can do a css hack like this:

```
select:focus ~ .clickable-div{
     pointer-events:none
}
.clickable-div{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

When the select is open (focus), it's sibling, `.clickable-div` will not respond to clicks.

```
<TableRowBody >
   ....
   <div onClick={(event) => onClickRow(rowItem, event)} className="clickable-div"></div>
   <select />
   ...
</TableRowBody>
```

Comment: This solution works! And I vaguely remember using this technique a long time ago. Thanks for the refresher!

Comment: Follow-up: the hrefs that are siblings to this row are using onClickRow instead of going to their href. Even using e.stopPropagation on the href does not work. Why would the href event be ignored?

Comment: Since i'm using MaterialUI, I was able to get the link to work by converting it to a Link Button. Whew!